# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden kentico administration

Tags: .net-core, kentico, kentico-mvc

I have installed kentico CMS and I choose default site DancingGoat. It creates all folders, and I manage to start project with VS2019. When I access http://localhost:8081/KenticoProject_DancingGoatMvc/ everything is fine. I can debug code as well. When I add /Admin, I got the error message:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

What is wrong with the admin part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, make sure your IIS site is looking not at the solution folder, but the MVC project folder. It should look like this:

[image]

Also, in visual studio right click on your project, then properties and choose option web. Check if you choose Local IIS option instead off IIS Express.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default URL of the administration interface is: `http://localhost/<target location folder>_Admin`, so in your case, it's probably `http://localhost:8081/KenticoProject_Admin/`